# Как отправить WAR архив при сборке maven-ом сразу на сервер?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-ee, maven, tomcat

Делаю в IDEA веб проект с помощью мавена. Выбираю цель packaging и мавен собирает мой проект в WAR архив и кладет его в папку /target директории проекта. При этом у меня отдельно запущен сервер TomCat .
Вопрос как сделать чтобы мавен при сборке WAR архива отправлял его сразу на сервер в директорию /webapps ???
Как это сделать подскажите?

Comment: в свое время делал [вот так](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat), нужно только вызывать из командной строки `mvn tomcat7:deploy`, такой вариант подойдет?

Comment: спасибо попробую